# Llenar <select> con ciclo for y condicional dentro de <option>

Tags: php, bucle-for, html-select

Tengo un archivo `index.php` desde donde quiero llenar un `<select>` con un `ciclo for` pero ademas quiero que un valor por defecto quede seleccionado.

He realizado en `laravel` este ejercicio y me parecio de lo mas normal posible, pero no entiendo porque en puro PHP me muestra el `<select>` sin valores.

**Laravel ejemplo, valor por defecto = 25**

```
<select>
   @for ($i = 18; $i <= 95; $i++) 
         <option @if ($i==25) selected 
                 @endif
         value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
   @endfor
 </select>
```

**PHP puro, mismo ejemplo anterior**

```
<?php

  for ($i=18; $i<=95; $i++){
      echo '<option'; if($i==25){ echo 'selected'; }' 
            value="'. $i.'">' . $i. '</option>';
   }
 ?>
```

Alguien ve un error o me da una idea de que puede estar fallando?
Agradecere cualquier comentario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal vez

```
echo '<option ' . ($i==25 ? 'selected ' : ''). ' value="'. $i.'">' . $i. '</option>';
```

Comment: Gracias Duston, no se me ocurrio usar un operador ternario para esto.